# Looking for a slang expression to say "I´m pissed off and sad. I want to be alone"

Tags: phrase-requests, slang

I found some things like *Being on the dumps*, but I would also like to say in the same line that I'd rather to be alone.

Comment: Is 'pissed off' too formal for you?

Comment: I would say, idiomatically, "in the dumps" rather than "on the dumps," as the latter implies that I am detritus.

Comment: It might not make much sense, but when you’re pissed off and sad, and just want to be left alone, you can turn the tables and tell everyone around to just “[piss off](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piss_off)”!

Comment: The idiomatic standard is Greta Garbo's [I **vant** to be alone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvHqUnRzh0s), but it's important to note that it's a **v**, not a **w**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers--In the clip you linked, Garbo clearly says "want," not "vant."

Comment: If you feel self-deprecatory (with a faint glint of humor), you might say "Let me wallow in my own misery/self-pity/sorrow/pool of sadness/etc." Another option is the phrase "I'm not fit for human company," which isn't so much slang as idiomatic English—but Google Books find instances of it going back to 1926.

Comment: The OP is specifically asking for slang. Unfortunately the variety of colloquialisms, including many phrases ending in "-off", is amazingly large, colorful, and unseemly.

Comment: "I'm pissed off" *is* slang, although its shock value has decreased over the years, it's still quite a strong expression, and a very effective one. If you had asked for a less aggressive expression, or a more "polite" idiom the question would have had a greater chance of surviving. Could you say "why" you discarded "pissed off" and "I want to be alone"?

Comment: What movie is the Greta Garbo line from?

Answer (score 1):

"I'd rather be left alone" is pretty common.

"I need some time to cool off" is also pretty common, and it implies that you're angry.

Similarly:

- I'd appreciate some time to myself.
- I'd like some personal time.
- I want some time to decompress.
- I need some **me-time**.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm in a foul mood and really wouldn't be very good company." is idiomatic and polite.